# Direct merge using Git [branches]

Tags: git, branch

I have 3 branches, in my proyecto.

Initial branch, where all the commit when they are correct are merge (Master)

And other 2 branches (Staging and Production) for pre-production and then production.

It tires me a lot every time there is a merge create a merge request from Master to Staging and from Staging to Master.

What I want to ask, is there a pipeline method or something for when a commit is done and it's merged to master branch, merge it directly to staging and then to master?

Comment: What are your 3 branches? You listed master twice.

Comment: My 3 branches, Master, Staging and Production

Comment: You merge after _every commit_?

Comment: If the commit is accepted we merge in master, then we have 2 more branches, staging and production, I what we do is first create a merge request from master to staging and then from staging to production @evolutionxbox

Comment: I would consider separating deployment environments from git. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery

Comment: Are you doing MASTER > STAGING > PRODUCTION right? readout [a-successful-git-branching-model](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Comment: That article doesn't have "staging" or "production" branches.